# Centering ul in div not working

Tags: css

I am trying to use `margin:auto` to center a ul tag into a parent div.
I am setting both to fixed widths, and `display:block` for the ul, but still nothing.

Here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/7y9qV/3/

Comment: May help:#thelist { display: inline-block;list-style: none;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you mean. The problem is, `<ul>` elements are actually rendered with a padding (in browsers that I've seen them in), which is causing the list to be pushed to the right.

To fix this, just add to your current definition for `#thelist`:

```
#thelist{
    padding:0;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y9qV/4/) that shows what this achieves. I hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: Oh right, uh, if this answer solved your problem, could you accept it as the correct answer? (Clicking the checkmark.) Thanks!